# android control to pan-tilt using accelerometer and gyroscope data

Tags: android, arduino, accelerometer, android-wifi, gyroscope

Sorry for doing this, I really don't know where to post beacuse this is both android studio code and arduino code so I post i both site.

I want to create a project of using controlling pan-tilt(2 servos combine) using the accelerometer and gyroscope data in smartphone. Creating android app and sending the accelerometer and gryroscope data to arduino so that the pan-tilt can determine its location.

My problem is when i connect the android app to arduino, no data shown in serial monitor of arduino and the pan-tilt is not locating the smartphone.
Please help me to solve this problem.....

this *MainActivity* is class to identify the data of accelerometer and gyrscope.

```
 MainActivity:
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener{

private final String TAG = "MainActivity";//log our activity

SensorManager sm;//define sensor manager
Sensor accelerometer, gyrometer;//define accelerometer

TextView xValue, yValue, zValue, xGyroValue, yGyroValue, zGyroValue;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    xValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.xValue);
    yValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yValue);
    zValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.zValue);

    xGyroValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.xGyroValue);
    yGyroValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yGyroValue);
    zGyroValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.zGyroValue);

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Initializing Sensor Services");

    sm =(SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);//permission to use the sensor

    accelerometer = sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    if (accelerometer != null) {

        sm.registerListener(MainActivity.this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Registered accelerometer listerner");
    }else {

        xValue.setText("accelerometer is not supported");
        yValue.setText("accelerometer is not supported");
        zValue.setText("accelerometer is not supported");
    }
    gyrometer = sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE);
    if (gyrometer != null) {

        sm.registerListener(MainActivity.this, gyrometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Registered gyrometer listerner");
    }else {

        xGyroValue.setText("gyrometer is not supported");
        yGyroValue.setText("gyrometer is not supported");
        zGyroValue.setText("gyrometer is not supported");
    }
}

public void connect(View v){

    DataSender dataSender = new DataSender();
    dataSender.execute((String) xValue.getText(), toString());
    dataSender.execute((String) yValue.getText(), toString());
    dataSender.execute((String) zValue.getText(), toString());
    dataSender.execute((String) xGyroValue.getText(), toString());
    dataSender.execute((String) yGyroValue.getText(), toString());
    dataSender.execute((String) zGyroValue.getText(), toString());

}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
    Sensor sensor = sensorEvent.sensor;
    if(sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){

        Log.d(TAG, "onSensorChanged: X: " + sensorEvent.values[0] + "Y: " + sensorEvent.values[1] + "Z:" + sensorEvent.values[2]);

        xValue.setText("xValue:   " + sensorEvent.values[0]);
        yValue.setText("yValue:   " + sensorEvent.values[1]);
        zValue.setText("zValue:   " + sensorEvent.values[2]);
    }else if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE){

        xGyroValue.setText("xGyroValue:   " + sensorEvent.values[0]);
        yGyroValue.setText("yGyroValue:   " + sensorEvent.values[1]);
        zGyroValue.setText("zGyroValue:   " + sensorEvent.values[2]);

    }

}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

}
}
```

this DataSender is class for sending the data to arduino.

```
DataSender:
public class DataSender extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

Socket s;
DataOutputStream dos;
PrintWriter pw;

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... voids) {

    String data = voids[0];

    try {
        s = new Socket("192.168.1.100",80);
        pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
        pw.write(data);
        pw.flush();
        pw.close();
        s.close();



    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    return null;
}
}
```

this is code that are uploaded in wifi module(esp8266-01) that are connected in arduino.

```
Arduino code:
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <Servo.h>

#define DEBUG true




char tiltChannel=0, panChannel=1;

//These are the objects for each servo.
Servo servoTilt, servoPan;

//This is a character that will hold data from the Serial port.
char serialChar=0;

// Center servos
int tiltVal = 90; 
int panVal =90; 

//smaartphone value
String inText;
float value0, value1, value2;


SoftwareSerial esp8266(10, 11); // RX, TX

void setup() { // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:

servoTilt.attach(2);  //The Tilt servo is attached to pin 2.
servoPan.attach(3);   //The Pan servo is attached to pin 3.
servoTilt.write(90);  //Initially put the servos both
servoPan.write(90);      //at 90 degress.

Serial.begin(9600); //for monitoring purposes
esp8266.begin(9600);

//sendCommand("AT+CIFS+RST\r\n", 2000, DEBUG); // reset module
sendCommand("AT+IPR=9600\r\n", 1000, DEBUG);
sendCommand("AT+CWMODE=1\r\n", 1000, DEBUG); // configure as access point
sendCommand("AT+CWJAP=\"EceConnect\",\"1234\"\r\n", 3000, DEBUG); //connec to 
a network with name EceConnect with password 1234
delay(1000);
sendCommand("AT+CIFSR\r\n", 1000, DEBUG); // get ip address
sendCommand("AT+CIPSTA=\"192.168.1.100\"\r\n", 1000, DEBUG);
sendCommand("AT+CIPMUX=1\r\n", 1000, DEBUG); // configure for multiple 
connections
sendCommand("AT+CIPSERVER=1,80\r\n", 1000, DEBUG); // turn on server on port 
80
Serial.println("Server Ready");

Serial.println("Android Sensor Type No: ");
Serial.println("1- ACCELEROMETER  (m/s^2 - X,Y,Z)");
Serial.println("2- GYROSCOPE (rad/s - X,Y,Z)");
Serial.flush();

}

void loop() { // run over and over

Serial.flush();
int inCommand = 0;
int sensorType = 0;
unsigned long logCount = 0L;

if (Serial.available() < 1) return; // if serial empty, return to loop().

char getChar = ' '; 
if (esp8266.available()) {
if (esp8266.find("+IPD,0,")) {
  delay(10);
  esp8266.find(":");
  delay(10);
  char letter = esp8266.read();
  Serial.print(letter); //for monitoring purposes
  //Gets the value/char from android app
  }
  }

  // parse incoming command start flag

  if (getChar != serialChar) return; // if no command start flag, return to 
  loop().

  // parse incoming pin# and value 
  sensorType = Serial.parseInt(); // read sensor typr
  logCount = Serial.parseInt();  // read total logged sensor readings
  value0 = Serial.parseFloat();  // 1st sensor value
  value1 = Serial.parseFloat();  // 2rd sensor value if exists
  value2 = Serial.parseFloat();  // 3rd sensor value if exists

  // send smartphone readings to serial monitor/terminal
  if (DEBUG) {
  Serial.print("Sensor type: ");
  Serial.println(sensorType);
  Serial.print("Sensor log#: ");
  Serial.println(logCount);
  Serial.print("Val[0]: ");
  Serial.println(value0);
  Serial.print("Val[1]: ");
  Serial.println(value1);
  Serial.print("Val[2]: ");
  Serial.println(value2);
  Serial.println("-----------------------");
  delay(10);
  }

  // Check sensor type. If not for  Accelerometer (#1) then ignore readings
  // sensorType 1 is the Accelerometer sensor

  if (sensorType !=1) return;   

  panVal = value0; // value0 = X sensor reading
  tiltVal = value1;  // value1 = Y sensor reading

  tiltVal = map(tiltVal, 10, -10, 0, 179);   // Map Accelerometer Y value to 
  tilt servo angle. 
  servoTilt.write(tiltVal);
  delay(10);

  panVal = map(panVal, -10, 10, 0, 179);  // Map Accelerometer X value to pan 
  servo angle.
  servoPan.write(panVal);     
  delay(10); 
  }






  String sendCommand(String command, const int timeout, boolean debug) {
  String response = "";
  esp8266.print(command); // send the read character to the esp8266
  long int time = millis();
  while ((time + timeout) > millis()) {
  while (esp8266.available()) {
  // The esp has data so display its output to the serial window
  char c = esp8266.read(); // read the next character.
  response += c;
  }
  }

  if (debug) {
  Serial.print(response);
  }
  return response;
  }
```